# Python string function ( isinstance) not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

As part of the homie-pythom implementation is the following code:

```
def isValidId(idString):
    """Validate device Id."""
    logger.debug("isIdFormat")
    if isinstance(idString, str):
        r = re.compile('(^(?!\-)[a-z0-9\-]+(?<!\-)$)')
        return True if r.match(idString) else False
```

Where idString has been read from a json file and should be 'cupboard'

```
print("Loading Config:" + configfile)
config = homie.loadConfigFile(configfile)
device = homie.Device(config)
```

config being a dict:

```
{
    "DEVICE_ID": "cupboard",
    "DEVICE_NAME": "cupboard",
}
```

Upon creating the homie.Device object with the config, the DEVICE_ID is passed through that string helper function ,which decides it's not valid.

I recreated the same code in my module:

```
print("Loading Config:" + configfile)
config = homie.loadConfigFile(configfile)
device = homie.Device(config)
print(config)
print("Config ID: " + config["DEVICE_ID"] + " Device Object iD:" + device.deviceId)
if device.deviceId != config["DEVICE_ID"]:
    print("homie.helpers.isValidId:")
    print(homie.helpers.isValidId(config["DEVICE_ID"]))

    print("isinstance(config['DEVICE_ID']:")
    print(isinstance(config["DEVICE_ID"], str))
    if isinstance(config["DEVICE_ID"], str):
        r = re.compile('(^(?!\-)[a-z0-9\-]+(?<!\-)$)')
        print(r.match(config["DEVICE_ID"]))
```

Where I get the following:

```
{u'DEVICE_ID': u'cupboard', u'DEVICE_NAME': u'cupboard'}
Config ID: cupboard Device Object iD:b827ebf8fa72
homie.helpers.isValidId:
None
isinstance(config['DEVICE_ID']:
False
```

You can see the isInstance(config['DEVICE_ID'],str) is getting a false.
This I think is the crux of my problem.....why is this?

This code is on python 3.7 on rwspberry pi.

Even doing natively in python does the same things:

```
>>> import homie
>>> config = homie.loadConfigFile('sensorconfig/homie-dht-raspups.json')
>>> print config
{u'DEVICE_ID': u'cupboard', u'DEVICE_NAME': u'cupboard'}
>>> print(isinstance(config["DEVICE_ID"], str))
False
```

Is it the u'cupboard'?

Comment: `u'....'` in your outputs suggests that you are actually running Python 2

Comment: In this case, your strings are unicode objects, which are not instances of `str`

Comment: Run `type(config["DEVICE_ID"])`, this will tell you the exact type

Comment: @ThierryLathuille yes 2.7.....which means I may have just solved my problem seeing that under python 3 this isn't as issue.   I just went through the code and updated all for python 3, and it works as expected.

Comment: So as pointed out, converting to python3 solves the issue.